# Error Handling in Android / Web View

Tags: android, url, webview

In an Android App, i have multiple buttons that load a website within a web view. These Webpages require a device token attached as a query string to be loaded successfully. If the Token is empty,
because the user didn't login, the url of the web view changes to "native-login://" i have to recognize that in my code and produce a native Error message. I tried accessing the WebView of my WebViewFragment - Object and requesting its URL - somehow this doesn't work properly and i can't find out why. Maybe the url didn't chance yet and the if()  is already executed? Sleeping the thread doesn't help.. Any ideas are much appreciated !

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int index, long l) {
    SidebarItem item = mTabtitles.get(index);
    Boolean isItemClicked = true;

    if (item.getType() == SidebarItemType.OFFER_SEARCH) {
        webViewFragment.loadUrl(URLRepo.URL_OFFER_SEARCH+ LoginActivity.ProfilToken.getToken());
    } else if (item.getType() == SidebarItemType.OFFER_ADD) {

        webViewFragment.loadUrl(URLRepo.URL_OFFER_ADD+ LoginActivity.ProfilToken.getToken());

        System.out.println("URL - result:"+WebViewFragment.webView.getUrl());

            if(WebViewFragment.webView.getUrl().equals("native-login://")) {
                System.out.println("Login Fehlgeschlagen");
            }


    }
```

Falco

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it by myself now. If anyone needs this: There us a method:

```
 @Override
    protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) { }
```

You can it override in the subclass of AsyncTask:

public class UserLoginTask extends AsyncTask{}

So you can easily progress the networking request in a separate process and don't get an exception.